# Converting type System.Linq.IQueryable<int> to int?

Tags: c#, linq, int

I'm currently working on assigning a variable the value of the ID from a database table.

```
var customerID = (from c in db.Customers
                 select c.CustomerID);
```

After which, I want to equate the value of the ID to the user's ID through an If Statement. However, I'm receiving:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'int?'

How do I convert the `IQueryable<int>` to `int?`?

Comment: Add .FirstOrDefault() to the end of the your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are selecting all the ids of your `Costumers` table, use [`FirstOrDefault`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb549141(v=vs.110).aspx) extension method or [`Find`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679596(v=vs.113).aspx):

```
var yourId=1;
//...
var customer = db.Customers.FirstOrDefault(c=>c.CustomerId==yourId);
```